# Form submits with href

Tags: forms, submit, href

Any suggestion to use href to submit a form when you have more than 1 submit?

```
  <form id="form-id">

    <input type='text'name='name'>

    <input type='submit' value='Preview' name='preview'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Add' name='add'/>



  </form>
```

I just know the way to do that using one submit in this way:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();"> submit </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

use this way:

```
<input type='submit' id='PrevSubmit' value='Preview' name='preview' 
style='display:none;' />

<input type='submit' id='addSubmit' value='Add' name='add' 
style='display:none;'/>
```

add two `a` tag like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
onclick="document.getElementById('PrevSubmit').click();">
  Preview 
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
onclick="document.getElementById('addSubmit').click();">
 Add </a>
```

Comment: just try to use submit inputs with none display to users and use anchor to do that.